# Interrupt and spinlock

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, spinlock

I understand that we disable `interrupts` when acquiring `spinlocks` in interrupt handlers.

I have a doubt as to what happens when a `spinlock` is held in `process context` and at that  instant an interrupt occurs ?

Can this scenario occur ?

As per my understanding if it so happens that the handler too try to acquire the same `lock` held in process context  , it would keep on spinning for that lock.

So do we always disable interrupts when acquiring `spinlock` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spinning is what spin locks are for.

When the interrupt happens on another CPU, it will spin only until the process-context lock has been unlocked.

When the interrupt happens on the same CPU, it would spin forever. This is why you should disable interrupts when taking a spin lock in process context, and if the same lock is also used by an interrupt handler.

(Disabling interrupts when taking a spin lock in interrupt context typically is not necessary because an interrupt handler cannot be interrupted by itself.)

Comment: It may happen that a higher priority interrupt may come when an interrupt has a spin lock , and that higher priority interrupt request that lock. So it is always better to disable interrupts when acquiring spin lock ?

Comment: You can avoid disabling interrupts only if you can prove that no (other) interrupt takes the same lock.

Comment: Interrupts can preempt eachother.